# Laravel Routes: Use ::controllers and ::post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Within Laravel, I currently have:

```
Route::controllers([
    'bla' => 'BlaController',
]);
```

But for a few specific methods within BlaController, I would like to pass parameters via the route (eg: `/bla/parameter`) and then be able to access that parameter within the controller.

However, declaring:

```
Route::get('bla/{parameter}', 'BlaController@exampleMethod');
```

keeps giving me a 404 not found when visiting it.

Is there some kind of conflict between using both declarations within `routes.php` and if so, is there a way to pass parameters to the controller for specific methods?

**Edit**: This is Laravel 5.1, if that makes any difference!

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this ?

```
   Route::get('/bla/{parameter}' ['uses'=>'BlaController@exampleMethod']);
```

http://laravel.io/forum/07-26-2014-routing-passing-parameters-to-controller

Comment: I still get a 404, but if I remove 'BlaController' from the controllers array, it works. There definitely seems to be some conflict, but I only want to manually route a couple of methods rather than all of them.

Comment: which version do u use ?

Comment: Laravel 5.1 on PHP 5.5.9

Comment: since you are using Route::controllers ensure you have `public function getIndex($param)` in your BlaController else it won't match